# implement google games services in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have uploaded an android game on the play store. I have made a windows 8 and windows phone 8 version of the same. I need to implement leaderboard, achievements and admob as implemented in the android version. I have found out the compatibility of admob for windows phone. Also I have found out that there is a .net library of Google Games Services. Will it work on these platforms? Most of the results of my search show that it wont while others dont mention it clearly.

Comment: I don't think that Google Gamer Services will work, maybe you can write an universal system. (ps. I use windows azure mobile services for this)

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently support for Google Play Game services on Windows phone.  Currently supported platforms are Android, iOS, and Web.